# how to draw root path when i am moving?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am implementing an app using Google Maps. When the app comes into the foreground I am getting the current position lat,long and push pin on the map.
But I require that when I am moving, I want to draw a root path based on my movement.
If any one knows the solution, please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: mu current location from app start to my moving path on google maps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to make a class which exends `Overlay`?

```
class MyOverlay extends Overlay{

public MyOverlay(){

}   

public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow){
    super.draw(canvas, mapv, shadow);

    Paint   mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);

    GeoPoint gP1 = new GeoPoint(19240000,-99120000);
    GeoPoint gP2 = new GeoPoint(37423157, -122085008);

    Point p1 = new Point();
    Point p2 = new Point();
    Path path = new Path();

    projection.toPixels(gP1, p1);
    projection.toPixels(gP2, p2);

    path.moveTo(p2.x, p2.y);
    path.lineTo(p1.x,p1.y);

    canvas.drawPath(path, mPaint);
}
```

Use it this way:

```
private List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
private Projection projection;  

mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();        
projection = mapView.getProjection();
mapOverlays.add(new MyOverlay());
```

Hope this helps!